# {skipLocationChange : true} in router.navigate not working; changing the state

Tags: angular, angular-routing, window-object

I am trying to embed Angular app on JSP page, for some reasons I need browser to preserve the state and don't want angular to push new state to browser history.

As per [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#replaceUrl) `{ skipLocationChange: true }` will allow me to do that. Below is my modified code.

```js
this.router.navigate(['/customComponent'],{ skipLocationChange: true });
```

still Angular is pushing new history state in browser history.

```js
state: {navigationId: 2}
```

Below is the console snapshot.

[image]

Is anything wrong with routing code? Or I am  missing any parameters.

Comment: I just tested it and it works perfectly fine. Would you mind posting the html of the button triggering the navigation and the ts of the component calling this.router.navigate ?

Comment: It worked for me as well when I created new app with bare bones, but not working in actual app, unfortunately because of organization policies I can not post actual code here, but will post some part of the code.

Comment: @BernardPagoaga , Below is the link of example I am trying but not working .
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eewr2h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Hey @BernardPagoaga I found the issue and adding the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was routing configuration in app.module.ts.
Since angular routes default path to `customComponent`, it modifies the state and there is no provision to pass `skipLocationChange` parameter, I had to reroute to customComponent using `skipLocationChange` from appComponent constructor which is bootstrapped in my case.

Directly bootstrapping customComponent will also help depending upon code written.

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: "/customComponent",
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. Could you please explain a little further?

Comment: For clarification, are you embedding angular app in JSP page?

Answer (score 0):

I use this this.router.navigate(['process-form/' + processDefCustomId + '/' + taskId], { skipLocationChange: true }); in constructor() and skipLocationChange: true doesn't work.

I move my code to the ngOnInit() method and skipLocationChange: true works.